# Factorial with Scala

Tags: scala, recursion

I am new to Scala and tying to understand recursion and tail recursion. When I write the program in single line, it's always giving me StackOverflow error, even for n=1 -

```
object Recursion extends App {
   def factorial(n: Int): Int = //if (n<=1) 1
     n * factorial( n - 1 )


  println( factorial( 1 ) )

}
```

vs

```
object Recursion extends App {

  def factorial(n: Int): Int = (

    if (n <= 1) 1
    else n * factorial( n - 1 )
    )

  println( factorial( 8 ) )
}
```

Gives correct value - 40320

Answer (score 2):

Got it, without `if (n<=1)`, it's going to infinite loop. That's why it never comes out and give this error.

Answer (score 1):

In problems solved via recursion, you must have a "branch/condition" that breaks the recursion and returns the accumulated value (aka pops the stack), or else the problem would never stop in theory; in practise all the calls to the function eventually overloads the memory allocated for the stack (i.e. StackOverflow error)

Notice also, that your function is recursive, but **it is not tail recursive**. For it to be **tail** recursive, the recursive call must the very last step.

To make it tail recursive you would have to do something like:

```scala
def factorial(n: Int): Int = {
  @tailrec
  def helper(n: Int, acc: Int): Int = {
    if (n == 1) acc
    else helper(n-1, n*acc)
  }
  helper(n, 1)
}
```

In your case, the last step is the **multiplication** `n*factorial(n-1)`. In my case, it is truly a call to itself.

Just to make things clear, in my example, `factorial` is not recursive (tail or otherwise), but the inner function `helper` is tail recursive.